# Why pyspark code running in the pycharm generate these information?

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I'm a green hand of python and pyspark. When I run the code of pyspark in pycharm, it always generate the information below. I want to know the reason and solution.

```html
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
    
�ɹ�: ����ֹ PID 15608 (���� PID 9980 �ӽ���)�Ľ��̡�
�ɹ�: ����ֹ PID 9980 (���� PID 7560 �ӽ���)�Ľ��̡�
�ɹ�: ����ֹ PID 7560 (���� PID 13296 �ӽ���)�Ľ��̡�
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem. I fixed it by adding following code:

```py
import os
os.system('chcp 65001') # explicitly changed encoding to utf-8
```

```html
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

SUCCESS: The process with PID 14228 (child process of PID 21804) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 21804 (child process of PID 9792) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 9792 (child process of PID 26488) has been terminated.
```